# Importing Shapefile geometry into SQL Server 2016?

Tags: shapefile, sql-server

What is the most preferred way to import shapefile geometry into MS SQL Server 2016?

Comment: see also https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/importing-spatial-data-to-sql-server-with-ogr2ogrnow-even-easier/

Answer (score 9):

Adding to klewis's answer: I got shape2sql.exe to work by adding a Shape2Sql.exe.config file with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

You can change the 14.0.0.0 to whichever version of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types is applicable to your version of SQL Server.

Comment: Not sure when this became a requirement, as this was working without this .config file early last year. Copy and pasting the above worked fine for me

Answer (score 3):

I use a free tool, shape2sql.exe, by SharpGIS.net. Because the tool is unmaintained you may need to copy and rename a dll, SqlServerSpatial110.dll or SqlServerSpatial120.dll to SqlServerSpatial.dll in C:\windows\system32. Also, clear out field "ID Column Name" for the data to import, I'm on Win10 64 bit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **ogr2ogr** library to import shapefile to SQL server, check below example and reference:

```
ogr2ogr
  -f "MSSQLSpatial" 
  "MSSQL:server=localhost\voledmort;database=myDB;trusted_connection=yes" 
  "countries.shp" 
  -a_srs "EPSG:2249"
```

**Reference:**
https://alastaira.wordpress.com/ogr2ogr-patterns-for-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in "GISquirrel" https://www.gisquirrel.com which includes a tool for importing any vector layer into your SQL Server database, working in ArcMap (It's an extension for ArcGIS Desktop). There's a free trial that works for 20 minutes per session and works with up to 10,000 features in a layer.