# How to deal with decimal separator when uploading geometries to MSSQL server using shape2sql.exe?

Tags: shapefile, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I'm using Shape2Sql.exe to upload .shp shapefile to MSSQL server 13.0.4502.0 on a Win10 64bit laptop. I've added Shape2Sql.exe.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

so that I could run the SqlServerSpatial130.dll correctly. Also erased ID Column name field (I found this suggestion on [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221417/importing-shapefile-geometry-into-sql-server-2016/258302)).

The geometry uploads correctly but latitudes and longitudes are in this format '524601.70435768971' '6525809.6313226018' and I think is a problem of the decimal separator character on shapefile but I couldnt find where to configure it.

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwgwy1hna2ailvf/ine_depto.shp?dl=0) is the .shp file I'm trying to upload.

Shape2Sql.exe is part of the [SqlSpatialTools](https://www.sharpgis.net/page/SQL-Server-2008-Spatial-Tools) software packege of www.sharpgis.net.